# Transposing Excel data without vbscript

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the transpose(column to row) of excel data, and I've created Macro for that which is working perfectly.
But I'm afraid what if the records exceeds the Excel's maximum row Capacity.
Is there any alternate way to do that.
Is it possible that if records exceeds in one sheet, it should populate the records in another sheet or another excel file.

```
Sub macro_generate()
Dim maxRows As Long
Dim maxCols As Long
Dim data As Variant

    Dim path As String
Dim openWb As Workbook
Dim openWs As Worksheet

path = "D:\Informatica\9.6.1\server\infa_shared\NL_Power_Exposure\bespoke.xlsx"

Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")


maxRows = openWs.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
maxCols = openWs.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxRows, maxCols))

Dim newSht As Worksheet
Set newSht = Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
With newSht

    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "IMPORTID"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "DT"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "READING"
  '  .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Linien Name"
  '  .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Einheit"
   ' .Cells(1, 6).Value = "Date"
    '.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Value"

    Dim writeRow As Long
    writeRow = 2

    Dim col As Long
    col = 2
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 2
    Dim row As Long

    Do While True

        row = 2
        Do While True

             'IMPORTID
            .Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = data(1, col)
            'DT
            .Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = data(row, 1)
            'READING
            .Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = data(row, col)


            writeRow = writeRow + 1
            counter = counter + 1

            If row = maxRows Then Exit Do 'Exit clause
            row = row + 1



        Loop

        If col = maxCols Then Exit Do 'exit cluase
        col = col + 1

    Loop

End With
openWb.Save
openWb.Close

End Sub
```

---

### SOURCE FILE

```
COLA    | COLB      | COLC
1-Jan-18| C1        | D1 
2-Jan-18| C2        | D2 
3-Jan-18| C3        | D3
```

---

### EXPECTED FILE

```
COLA    | COLB 
1-Jan-18| C1   
2-Jan-18| C2   
3-Jan-18| C3   
1-Jan-18| D1   
2-Jan-18| D2   
3-Jan-18| D3
```

Comment: Since there are more rows in Excel than columns you cannot exceed the rows when transposing from columns to rows. Also if you try to access a cell beyond the maximum row/column of Excel it would throw an error, so you will notice that. There is no silent loss of data.

Comment: Is there is an option, at least I can paste the exceeding rows in another sheet.

Comment: There are no exceeding rows. This can not happen when transposing columns to rows. Excel has `1048576` rows but only `16384` columns. That is 64 times the amount of columns. If you still think it does happen please provide a [mcve] to proof it. I never saw a case where `1048576` rows wasn't enough. If that is the case you should really think about a real database instead of an Excel sheet.

Comment: I've added example, if you look at that currently I've date(column A) around 32 k rows, when the column increases then how can I handle?

Comment: Ah, well, that is no real "transpose". But if that combining action exceeds your rows you should think about using a database instead of Excel. If you split it up into 2 sheets your data becomes pretty useless and hard to handle I think (depends what you want to do with it later). But you can check if `row > .Cells.Rows.Count` and then start at row 1 in a new sheet. Try that and if you get stuck come back with a concrete question about your code.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
Sub CombineColumns1()
'updateby Extendoffice 20151030
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xLastRow As Integer
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xLastRow = xRng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1
    For i = 2 To xRng.Columns.Count
        Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Columns(i).Rows.Count, i)).Cut
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=xRng.Cells(xLastRow, 1)
        xLastRow = xLastRow + xRng.Columns(i).Rows.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

Or...

```
Sub CombineColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lastCell As Integer

Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.Count
    Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.Count
Next iCol
End Sub
```

Also...consider copying to a new sheet, if you exceed the row limit.

```
If j > 1048576 Then
    j = 2
    Set finalSheet = Sheets("Sheet2") 'create new sheet
End If
```